# Последнее изменение файлов в директории в С

Tags: c

Написал код, который с помощью рекурсии проходится по всем папкам и выводит файлы и их директрории но мне нужно добавить сюда запись о последнем изменении файла. Как это сделать?

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void listdir(const char *name, int indent)
{
    DIR *dir;
    struct dirent *entry;
    if (!(dir = opendir(name)))
    return;

    while ((entry = readdir(dir)) != NULL) {
        if (entry->d_type == DT_DIR) {
            char path[1024];
            if (strcmp(entry->d_name, ".") == 0 || strcmp(entry-            
              >d_name, "..") == 0)
            continue;
        snprintf(path, sizeof(path), "%s/%s", name, entry->d_name);
        printf("%*s[%s]\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
        listdir(path, indent + 2);
    } else {
        printf("%*s- %s\n", indent, "", entry->d_name);
    }
}
closedir(dir);
}

int main(void) {
    listdir(".", 0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [man 2 stat](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=stat&category=2) же.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

#if 0
               struct timespec st_atim;  /* время последнего доступа */
               struct timespec st_mtim;  /* время последней модификации */
               struct timespec st_ctim;  /* время последнего статуса изменения */
#endif


int main ( )
{
    struct stat st;
    stat ( "file", &st );
    time_t t = st.st_mtim.tv_sec;
    printf ( "%s\n", ctime ( &t ) );

}
```

сначала в структуру нужно записать информацию о файле. Потом получить время в секундах и вывести дату.